# Camera bug on iOS 13.3 PWA

Tags: javascript, ios, vuejs2, camera

I noticed a weird thing in my company’s PWA recently. After you use a file input to take a picture, afterwards you close (I mean not forced close but just going out and in) an app for a 2–3s and you re-open. If you try to lunch camera again the image will be blank. It happens on iOS.

Have you guys encountered such a thing yourself and if you did, can you suggest some kind of solution? I was thinking about using WebRTC but this hack with an input is much more convenient.

My Camera Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="camera-container" :class="{ 'open': open }">
    <div class="panel" v-if="base64Source">
      <div class="title pb-2 text-center">
        {{ title }}
      </div>
      <button @click="upload" class="btn button mt-2">Wyślij i przejdź dalej</button>
      <label for="camera-file-input" class="btn button outlined mt-2">Wykonaj jeszcze raz</label>
      <button @click="cancel" class="btn button outlined mt-2">Anuluj</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="subtitle">Podgląd</div>
        <hr class="hr pt-0 mt-0">
        <img :src="base64Source" alt="Podgląd" class="w-100">
        <div class="row mt-3 mb-0" v-if="fileName">
          <div class="col-6"><label class="">Nazwa dokumentu:</label></div>
          <div class="col-6 mb-0"><label class="">{{ fileName }}</label></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form v-show="!open" ref="camera-file-input-form" id="camera-file-input-form">
      <label for="camera-file-input" class="button pink btn camera-file-input-label">
        {{ btnName }}
      </label>
      <input v-on:change="imageChanged"
             id="camera-file-input"
             type="file"
             accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/gif"
             capture="environment"
             class="invisible"
      >
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    btnName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      open: false,
      fileName: '',
      base64Source: null,
      blobSource: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    upload () {
      this.$emit('upload', this.blobSource)
      this.clear()
    },
    cancel () {
      this.clear()
    },
    clear () {
      this.$refs['camera-file-input-form'].reset()
      this.base64Source = null
      this.blobSource = null
      this.open = false
    },
    async imageChanged (event) {
      const cameraInput = event.target
      this.open = true
      if (cameraInput.files && cameraInput.files[0]) {
        const file = cameraInput.files[0]
        this.blobSource = file
        this.base64Source = await this.convertToBase64(file)
      }
    },
    convertToBase64 (file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const fileReader = new FileReader()

        if (fileReader && file) {
          fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
          fileReader.onload = () => {
            resolve(fileReader.result)
          }
          fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
            reject(error)
          }
        } else {
          // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-promise-reject-errors
          reject(null)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

We have been experiencing this same issue with our app that our users commonly run as a PWA.

There are additional StackOverflow threads on this same topic here:

[IOS camera returns black screen after leaving pwa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422838/ios-camera-returns-black-screen-after-leaving-pwa) 
[iOS Standalone PWA input capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254979/ios-standalone-pwa-input-capture)

This bug has also been reported to webkit here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206219

Unfortunately, I have yet to find anyone who has a decent workaround other than not allowing users on iOS 13.2 & 13.3 to run your app as a PWA. (The bug doesn't occur when running inside the browser.)

Comment: Thank you for adding the info and the bug report. Thanks to those, I have found out (and personally confirmed) that this has been resolved in the latest version (13.5.1, fixed in 13.4+)

Comment: The bug seems to be back in version 16.5.1 (c).

Comment: Correction: PWA/bookmark needed to be deleted and reinstalled/readded to home screen, then it worked.